# Check for dependence in n equations

Tags: algorithm, math, equation-solving

How can we check if the given set of n equations in n variables is linearly dependent or not in O(n) or something less than O(n^2)?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the types equations? If you have n linear equation in n variables your input is n² coefficients, and just reading the input is O(n²)...

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we get a matrix M from those n equations in n variables.

The maxtirx M and the equations in n variables are linearly dependent if and only if:

```
Rank(M) < n
```

The following question is how to calculate the rank of a matrix. We can use Gaussian elimination and Gauss-Jordan elimination to complete it, as listed in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29#Computing_the_rank_of_a_matrix).

You may check more details and proofs from:

www.edmeasurement.net/matrix/notes/Dependence%20and%20Rank.pdf

www.enm.bris.ac.uk/teaching/enbwp/MAPLE1/Matrix2-d.pdf‎

Comment: ... and Gauss-Jordan elimination is `O(n^3)`, which is not as fast as OP was wanting.  But to be fair, I would not be surprised if `O(n^3)` is the best possible.